# Is Autoescape default in jinja2 (Flask)?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am researching some security bugs within some websites and would like to know if jinja2 enables autoescape by default. According to the Jinja documentation (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/faq/#why-is-autoescaping-not-the-default), it doesn't, but while I was testing the app on a new system, it was enabled (I may have accidentally done that though, not sure.

Can anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`flask` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#jinja-setup):

Unless customized, Jinja2 is configured by Flask as follows:

> autoescaping is enabled for all templates ending in .html, .htm, .xml as well as .xhtml when using `render_template()`.

Also:

> autoescaping is enabled for all strings when using `render_template_string()`.

Finally:

> a template has the ability to opt in/out autoescaping with the `{% autoescape %}` tag.

So, while `jinja` may not autoescape by default, `flask` turns on Jinja's autoescaping by default.

Answer (score 3):

As @mgilson answer states, autoescape is NOT enabled by default on all files, but only on those ending with `.html`, `.htm`, `.xml` and `.xhtml`. Not everyone uses these extensions because they may be misleading: the code they contain is not normal (X)HTML code, but rather Jinja templates; to clarify this some people use the extension `.j2`.

In order to enable autoescape for all files regardless of their extension, one can use the following code:

```
app.jinja_options["autoescape"] = lambda _: True
```